# Test command in unix doesn't print an output

Tags: bash, shell, command, test

When I type this in the terminal

```
test 4 -lt 6
```

I don't get any output. Why not? I need that 0 or 1

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if 'test' had an option to output a value immediately? Just the option. That's all we'd need.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You get 0 or 1. In the exitcode.

```
bash-4.2$ test 4 -lt 6

bash-4.2$ echo $?
0

bash-4.2$ test 4 -gt 6

bash-4.2$ echo $?
1
```

**Update**: To store the exitcode for later use, just assign it to a variable:

```
bash-4.2$ test 4 -lt 6

bash-4.2$ first=$?

bash-4.2$ test 4 -gt 6

bash-4.2$ second=$?

bash-4.2$ echo "first test gave $first and the second $second"
first test gave 0 and the second 1
```

Comment: is there a way to pipe the exit code?

Comment: No. Only output can be redirected. Anyway, usually there is no need for that. To store it for later use, just assign it to a variable. Or tell us what exactly is your intention with that value.

Comment: The exit code is placed into the `$?` variable -- at least until it gets overwritten by the next command you execute.

Comment: PS: You can use [the `$PIPESTATUS` array](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PIPESTATUSREF) to get the result of multiple commands in a pipeline. `$?` will by be the result of the *last* command in the pipeline if [the `pipefail` option](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html#PIPEFAILREF) is off (the default).

Comment: @indieman, if what you need is to do something else based on the exit status, you don't even need to save it—just use `if test 4 -lt 6; then echo test succeeeded; else echo test failed; fi`

Answer (score 8):

Another way is

```
test 4 -lt 6 && echo 1 || echo 0
```

But be careful in that case. If `test` returns success and `echo 1` fails `echo 0` will be executed.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the result of a comparison on standard out instead of an exit code, you can use the `expr(1)` command:

```
$ expr 4 '<=' 6
1
```

Two things to note:

1. you will likely need to quote the operator as a lot of them conflict with shell metacharacters
2. the output value is the opposite of the return code for `test`. `test` returns 0 for true (which is the standard for exit codes), but `expr` prints 1 for true.

Comment: 3. There is a `test` shell builtin, which is considerably faster (about 50 times on my machine) than the `test` and `expr` executables from the _coreutils_ package.

Comment: +1 for the second point. Could get a bug that is very frustrating to find if you mess that up.

Answer (score 3):

You may type in the following command:

```
echo $(test -e myFile.txt) $?
```